# Converting circuits to C

Tags: c, simulator, control-theory

Does anyone have an idea on how to convert a feedforeward opamp PID loop to C code? I am trying to do such a conversion and honestly, have no idea where to start. I can get all input values through an ADC, voltage, current, whatever, but coding a feedforeward PID is a little new to me. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure "PID" is the right tag for your question? Its current description is exclusively about "process IDs". Perhaps your question could be made a bit more verbose.

Comment: PID in this context is probably a [proportional-integral-differential controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PID_controller).  And op-amp is an [operational amplifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier).  So, as the title suggests, the question is somehow related to how to code up a simulation of an operational amplifier with a feed-forward loop in C.  And it is sufficiently long since I last thought about these terms that I've not got a clue on how to go about solving the problem.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler My first idea is simply making a function that sums a function, its derivative and its integral... Isn't that a solution?

Comment: @H2CO3: pass — I'd need to think harder than I've thought in nearly 30 years about how op-amps are characterized, and we'd need to know how the feed-forward loop is connected, and ... generally, we'd need a lot more information than we have.  And then there'd be issues with how to code.  There are whole languages for circuit simulation, though they may be more commonly for microchip work than this which I'd characterize as 'macrochip' (or discrete devices rather than a chip at all).

Comment: I think this is described first in "s-domain circuit analysis" and then the result can be discretised with eg. bilinear transform to z-domain. From that point on, the c algorithm is easy. P in the PID means amplifying input by factor K. D means taking successive samples from the input stream, multiplying them with weights b1,b2,b3 (taking e.g. 3 last samples) and I means feedback loop, where one adds to the result N last results of the circuit again with some weights a1,a2,a3.

Answer (score 1):

You are talking about replacing hardware with software for a non-linear control system.  I think your only hope is to write a simulation of the hardware.

I don't know anything about PIDs, but a quick Google search found this:

http://www.cds.caltech.edu/~murray/books/AM05/pdf/am06-pid_16Sep06.pdf

It has equations and graphs that appear to describe an ideal PID control system.  You might start by writing code that implements those equations.

After I thought about your question a bit, it seemed to me that this might be a common problem.  I did a Google search for "discrete PID controller simulation" and found Simulink, Matlab, and Python answers, as well as more references to books.

You might want to start with the Python recipe.  Python is easier and faster to play around with than C, and if you use SciPy you can plot your results and make sure you are getting the numbers you want.  Once you have it working in Python, then port to C if needed.

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577231-discrete-pid-controller/

Comment: Thanks! I will look into this. I am sampling a voltage wave, so my inputs come from an ADC, I have to simulate the op-amp PID, and I need to use te utput to control a device. I wil definitely ceck it out though. Thanks!!!

Comment: I really appreciate that pure software guys do come up to solve electronics/electrical problems :)  simulation for analysis and simulation for using in real world has certain limitation. And one big one is the choice of language when it comes to compiling the code into embedded system. I believe this question should be asked in some embedded forums rather than in here.

Answer (score 1):

### The Circuit

Seems like the analog circuit you want to simulate using C looks something like this

```
                         Ci
                  |------| |--------------|
                  |           Rp          |
                  |----/\/\/\/\-----------|
                  |          Rd    Cd     |
           Rf     |----/\/\/\---| |-------|
Vin o----/\/\/\---|                       |
                  |    |\                 |
                  |    | \                |
                  |----|- \               | 
                       |   \              |
                       |    \-------------|---------o  Vout
                       |    /
                       |   /
                       |+ /
                   ----| /
                  |    |/
                  |
                  |
               ___|___ GND
                _____
                 ___
                  _

LEGEND:
  Vin is the input signal.
  Vout is the Output.
  Rp controls the propotional term ( P in PID) 
  Ci controls the Integral term ( I in PID)
  Rd and Cd controls the differential term ( D in PID)
  Rf is the gain control, which is common to all of the above controllers.
```

I strongly suggest you use the circuit from [this source](http://www.mae.ncsu.edu/silverberg/piddocs.pdf) for studying.
[image: : Complete circuit diagram for PID controller]

Even though a little tedious to set up, mathematically its much simpler to analyse as you can directly relate it to the standard mathematical form instead of ideal one.

Lastly the Vout goes to control a motor or whatever needs to be controlled. And Vin is the Process variable voltage.

### Before getting your feet wet in C (sea?)

I assume you are reading the signals from some kind of analogue to digital converter. If not then you would have to simulate the signal as an input.

If using Standard form we have,

[image]

Assuming the the loop running time is small enough (a slow process), we can use the following function for calculating output,

```
PIDoutput = Kp * err + (Ki * int * dt) + (Kd * der /dt);
```

where

```
Kp = Proptional Constant.
Ki = Integral Constant.
Kd = Derivative Constant.
err = Expected Output - Actual Output ie. error;
int  = int from previous loop + err; ( i.e. integral error )
der  = err - err from previous loop; ( i.e. differential error)
dt = execution time of loop.
```

where initially 'der' and 'int' would be zero. If you use a delay function in code to tune the loop frequency to say 1 KHz then your dt would be 0.001 seconds.

Now the output of a feedforward system would be,

```
FeedForwardOutput = Kf * Vin;
```

where
    Kf = Propotional constant for feedforward system.

Thus the total output of our feedforward system with PID controller would be,

```
Output = FeedForwardOutput + PIDoutput;
```

Check this [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PID_controller#Feed-forward) for further reading about feedfoward system with PID controller.

### Drawning in C

I found [this](http://www.embeddedheaven.com/pid-control-algorithm-c-language.htm) excellent code for PID in C, though it doesn't cover every aspect of it, its a good one nonetheless.

```
//get value of setpoint from user
while(1){
  // reset Timer
  // write code to escape loop on receiving a keyboard interrupt.
  // read the value of Vin from ADC ( Analogue to digital converter).
  // Calculate the output using the formula discussed previously.
  // Apply the calculated outpout to DAC ( digital to analogue converter).
  // wait till the Timer reach 'dt' seconds.
}
```

If we take a slow process, then we can use lower frequency such that dt >>> code execution time for single loop ( far far greater than ). In such cases we can do away with timer and use a delay function instead.

Comment: Wow!! Tons of info!! Thanks!! For starters, I am reading the levels through a 12 bit ADC built into a TI 320F28335 DSP processor. The ansi version of the circuit you drew is what I have to convert to code. I unfortunately am not allowed the luxury of time or parts to build and study the other one, otherwise, I'd be all for it!!! Also- for clarification, my sampling frequency is 40kHz, so every 25us.

Comment: Also, I have no Rf on my circuit... So what determines the constants Kp, Ki, and Kd? and where did Kf come from? Can those constants be varied by voltage automatically or are they fixed until changed? This stuff is a bit confusing.. but your explanation shined a little light, thanks!!

Comment: I had never worked on that processor, but i suspect it would be able to give you a loop execution time better than 1ms, forget 25us. Maybe we can try using double instead of float and optimize the code. I strongly suggest you to try out with some sampling rate of 100Hz. Regarding other queries i will modify the answer.

Comment: Before i edit, i would like to know few things Are you sure you are designing Hybrid Feed Forward PID controller or just PID controller ( which works in feedback mode ) ? If its just PID controller then we wont need FeedForwardOutput, hence no Kf in equation. Secondly there have to be a Rf, if its not there on the circuit it might be the source resistance of Vin. Absence of Rf would mean infinite gain and the output would saturate, Please confirm. ( Btw, the second diagram is easier to analyze, the ASCII art is quite complicated, mathematically).

Comment: that TI chip is a 32 bit floating point processor running at 150MHz. So to clarify, I'm not designing, it's already been done by someone else. I'm converting it to C code, and the circuit is like the ASCII art version drawn above. However, I would like to know how to code both of them, but right now, if time is pressing, I only need the PID controller. Feed-foreward is not necessary at this time. I did locate Rf, apologies for not looking sooner, it was actually on another page of the schematic. And again, Thanks for your help with this, they don't teach this in school...